# node.js - populate embedded document in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Given:**

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  details : [{ name: String,  description: String }]
})


var listSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  products: [{
    product_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
    product_vid: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product.details' }
    }]
})
```

How can I do the query for the List with only corresponding product_id with one details matching product_vid in it?

```
List.findById(list_id)
    .populate({
       path: 'products.product_id',
       populate: {
         path: 'products.product_vid'
       }
     })
     .exec(function(err, doc){
       ......
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for

```
product_vid: {
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product.details'}
```

in listSchema.

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
details : [{ name: String,  description: String }]
     })


var listSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }])

      List.findById(list_id)
        .populate({
              path: 'products',
              match: { details: "your matching value"})
           .exec(function(err, doc){
                  ......
      }
```

Comment: If I delete the product_vid, then how can I populate the products with the corresponding details?       Like the match value is the _id in details and I need to find a way to store it somewhere in the list?

Comment: you will get back the whole array, not just the array element that caused the match.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
product_vid: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product.details' }
```

detail is field of a model. and not model itself.

it should be something like..

```
 var listSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }],
})
```

and then

```
 populate('products')
```

or probably

```
 populate('products products.details')
```

Just try and let me know.

Comment: it doesnt work... i've tried it before.  It shows error that says: "Schema hasn't been registered for model product.details"

Comment: did you mean product.detail or products.product_id?  ah ok.. I guess this is wrong .  product_vid: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product.details' }

Comment: but then how do i get the right version of details?  I only want to get the right product with the right details.. ( Thats why I put a product_vid inside the product array in List )